# Scala- How to get a Vector's contained class?

Tags: scala, reflection, collections, scala-collections

Does Scala have a way to get the contained class(es) of a collection? i.e. if I have:

```
val foo = Vector[Int]()
```

Is there a way to get back classOf[Int] from it?

(Just checking the first element doesn't work since it might be empty.)

Comment: [What are you actually trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)  What do you expect to do with this class object once you have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getType[F[_], A: TypeTag](as: F[A]) = typeOf[A]

val foo = Vector[Int]()
getType(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not from the collection itself, but if you get it a parameter from a method, you could add an implicit `TypeTag` to that method to obtain the type at runtime. E.g.

```
def mymethod[T](x: Vector[T])(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = ...
```

See [https://docs.scala-lang.org/.../typetags-manifests.html](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html#using-an-implicit-parameter-of-type-typetagt-classtagt-or-weaktypetagt) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can do it by using TypeTag or Typeable/TypeCase from Shapless library (see [link](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala)). But I just want to note that all these tricks are really very advanced solutions when there is no any better way get the task done without digging inside type parameters.

All type parameters in scala and java are affected by type erasure on runtime, and if you сatch yourself thinking about extracting these information from the class it might be a good sign to redesign the solution that you are trying to implement.